# Printing an 8-bit number in hexadecimal with IO manipulators

Tags: c++

I have a `uint8_t` and want to convert it to a two-digit hex string in C++ in the same way that the format string `%02x` would.

To do this, I've enlisted the help of a `stringstream` and IO manipulators to configure how the stream should format numbers:

```cpp
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    uint8_t x = 3;
    std::cout << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0')
              << x << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

So this should print `03` right? No, it prints `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Standard Libraries implementation of `<cstdint>` (btw. ... you didn't include it and `uint8_t` is in the namespace `std`) uses a typedef for `uint8_t`:

```
namespace std {
    // ...
    typedef char unsigned `uint8_t`
    // ...
};
```

so `std::ostream` interprets it as character, not as an integer type. To make sure it gets interpreted as an integer just cast it explicitly:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::uint8_t x{ 3 };
    std::cout << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0')
              << static_cast<int>(x) << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it prints `0\0x03`. That's right, it interprets the variable `x` as a character, not as a number.

The correct way to do this is to use the unary plus operator:

```cpp
std::cout << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0')
          << +x << std::endl;
```

Comment: The `+x` just disguises an implicit cast to `int`. If you want a cast, write a cast: `std::cout << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << static_cast<int>(x) << '\n';`

Comment: I am 50:50 on this. Used consistently the operator + has well defined integral promotion meaning and avoids accidental down-casting of a 64-bit to 32-bit, for example. Used rarely, it is just confusing.